# add a backgound color to the active link on my bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a background color to the active link on my bootstrap navbar that will look similar to the one shown in the image below. I've selected nav-link active and made it red in the css but I haven't been successful. [image: Navbar Image example]

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/personal-protection-s/1820.htm">PPE</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/default.asp">CLOTHING</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/category-s/1899.htm">FOOTWEAR</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="Contact.html">LOGIN</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>




.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
color: #cccccc;
```

}

```
.nav-link active {
color: red
```

}

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to use `.` before `active`:**

```
.nav-link.active {
background-color: red
}
```

```css
.nav-link.active {
background-color: red}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/personal-protection-s/1820.htm">PPE</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/default.asp">CLOTHING</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/category-s/1899.htm">FOOTWEAR</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="Contact.html">LOGIN</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks,  '.nav-link:active' didn't work but I added a dot before the 'active' class which sorted everything out.

Comment: I edited my answer (before you worte comment)look at edit(refresh page)

Comment: use `.nav-link.active`

Comment: Thanks, How would I go about making the whole Login In section red? Like shown in the image earlier

Comment: with `background-color` and not `color`... see in my answer run snippet

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/Webi13/8eh2rk6n/) I'm trying to get rid of the grey parts at the top and bottom of the page

Comment: use `.navbar {
    background-color: #2a2f35;
    padding: 0!important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a dot before `active` class and also you need to get rid of the space before it, because both of the classes are in the same element. So you don't need space between them. Try this code.

```
.nav-link.active {
    color: red
}
```